# Contador automático de un elemento de arreglo con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código en Python y lo quiero hacer más eficiente,
la pregunta seria como me pudo ahorrar las condicionas por cada elemento del arreglo

Necesito tener algo parecido a esta salida:

> [4 1] [4 2] [4 3] [4 4] [5 1] [5 2] [5 3]

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
r = b[3]
z = b[4]
i = 0
k = 0
for temp in a:
    if temp == r:
        i += 1
        print(temp, i)
    if temp == z:
        k += 1
        print(temp, k)
```

Comment: de que forma lo quieres optimizar? menos código?. tiempo de ejecución? (aunque en este problema, no importa eso)

Comment: Quiero menos código, específicamente en la parte del IF, quiero evitar tener que declarar un if por cada elemento

Comment: lo veo un poco difícil, por que en cada `if` cambias una variable distinta

Comment: Puedes reemplazar el segundo `if` por `elif`, ya que es una misma variable en ambos `if`, y sólo puede tener un valor.

Answer (score 1):

Las operaciones con listas están super optimizadas en Python. En general, resulta más eficiencia en tiempo y espacio usar una comprensión de listas en lugar de un ciclo iterativo explicito.

Una solución usando comprensión de listas:

```
def secuencia(lista, valor):
    return [(valor, i + 1) for i in range(lista.count(valor))]
```

La función recibe una lista y el valor a extraer. Retorna una lista de tuplas (valor, secuencia).

No tiene mucha ciencia. El valor es siempre el mismo (recibido como parámetro) y la secuencia es siempre 1, 2, 3, ...

#### Demo

```
def secuencia(lista, valor):
    return [(valor, i + 1) for i in range(lista.count(valor))]

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
r = b[3]
z = b[4]
i = 0
k = 0
print(secuencia(a, r))
print(secuencia(a, z))
```

produce:

```
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
```